# Expects parameter 1 to be resource error for Fopen and fwrite

Tags: php

My code is perfectly creating the folder and file. But i want that, all the newly created folders must go in a parent folder.
For now, it creates folders in the root directory. But i want that it should create folder and file in a sub folder like "docs/then new folders should come here with files in it".

I get some errors when i try to put folders and files in a sub folder, though it creates the directory but files aren't being created.

Here is the code

```
<?php  
    $dirname = $_POST["name"];  
    $filename = "/{$dirname}/";  
    
    if (file_exists($filename)) {  
        echo "The directory {$dirname} exists";  
    } else {  
        mkdir("User Folders/{$dirname}/", 0777, true);  
    $content = "Name:".$_POST["name"]." Email:".$_POST["email"]; 
    $fp = fopen($_POST["name"]."User Folders/Customer Details.txt","wb"); 
    fwrite($fp,$content); 
    fclose($fp); 
        echo "The directory {$dirname} was successfully created.";  
    }  
?>
```

Here is the error

> Warning: fopen(TeamthunderUser Folders/Customer Details.txt): failed
> to open stream: No such file or directory in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\fj\badmin\CreateFolder.php on line 10
>
> Warning: fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\fj\badmin\CreateFolder.php on line 11
>
> Warning: fclose() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\fj\badmin\CreateFolder.php on line 12 The directory
> Teamthunder was successfully created.

Comment: `fopen()` couldn't find the file you told it to open, so it returned `false`.

Comment: You're obviously not giving the correct pathname to the file that you want to open. Maybe you left out the directory part of the pathname? Without seeing the code it's impossible to tell what you're doing wrong.

Comment: yes that i have seen in the stackoverflow. But i couldn't figure out yet, how to fix it

Comment: sorry i forgot to enter the code

Comment: just added the code.

Comment: Why do you leave out `User Folders` when calling `file_exists()`?

Comment: Didn't Noticed. How can i write that. Still trying to make it work correctly. Not an expert much

Comment: `if (file_exists("User Folders/$direname"))` Why isn't that obvious?

Comment: Why do you think it's not the same for all the functions?

Comment: It is. Actually i tried many codes and was running them. Possibly gets slipped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The directory you created is within `User Folders`. But you're putting `$_POST['name']` *before* `User Folders`. It should be:

```
$fp = fopen("User Folders/$dirname/Customer Details.txt","wb");
```

Comment: Barmar thank you soo much. You saved hours of me. 
Lastly if you can guide me display the folders that i have created on front end. 
I am using this code

<?php
          $files = scandir('.');
          foreach($files as $file){
           if($file != "." && $file != ".." && $file != "css" && $file != "fonts" && is_dir($file)){
         ?>
          <tr>
           <td><?php echo $file."<br />";?></td>
           <td><?php echo realpath($file) ?></td>
          </tr>
         <?php
           }

          }
         ?>

Comment: You should be scanning the `User Folders` directory, not `.`

Comment: And you'll then need `realpath("User Folders/$file")`

Comment: I have used this and it is not showing me anything. i have edited as you asked. 

<?php $files = scandir('User Folders'); 
       foreach($files as $file){ 
        if($file != "." && $file != ".." && $file != "css" && $file != "fonts" && is_dir($file)){ 
       ?> 
       <tr>
        <td>
        <?php echo $file."<br />";?></td>
        <td><?php echo realpath("User Folders/$file") ?></td>
       </tr> 
       <?php } } ?>

Comment: If you have a new problem, please post another question. I'm not going to try to answer it in comments.

Comment: `is_dir("User Folders/$file")` -- don't you get it? You ALWAYS need the directory prefix.

Comment: Sorry Barmar. I understand. Actually i am trying to achieve this. Display all folders like we see in windows. So i can double click on a Folder and open it. After that i need to create a form in folder. Form i can handle. But i need to display like Folders icons and then by double clicking the folder to open it.

Comment: Sounds like you need a recursive procedure to handle nested folders.

Comment: It is like dropbox system for my college project

Comment: I understand what you're trying to do. I feel like it's too advanced for you.

Comment: Much respect and thanks to you Barmar. I don't know is it possible for you to guide me further on this. But i appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

You may have forgotten a slash / after

```
$fp = fopen($_POST["name"]."
```

Comment: USed Slash as you said, but same error

$fp = fopen($_POST["name"]."/User Folders/Customer Details.txt","wb");

Comment: Does the full path exist at that point?

Comment: yes the path exist. Folder gets created but not the file. I have created a folder named User Folders in the root directoy.